# How to scope validation to specific model in polymorphic association.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two model `User` and `Investment` and one polymorhic model `Address`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :address, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Investment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: lambda { |v| v['address'].blank? } && :address_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
   validates :address, presence: true
end
```

now `validates :address, presence: true` will applicable to both `Investment` as well as `User`
but i want it to applicable to only `Investment` not to `User`. so how do i do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in class Investment add

```
validates :address_id, presence: true
```

and remove bellow from class Address

```
validates :address, presence: true
```

Comment: its polymorphic , my investment model didn't  have investment_id,

Answer (score 0):

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
   validates :address, presence: true, if: :investment?

   protected

   def investment?
     addressable_type == 'Investment'
   end
end
```

Comment: I don't know why but this is not working...after i added your changes, my Investment record saved with blank address,